# How to use a spark dataframe as a table in a SQL statement

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a spark dataframe in python.  How do I use it in a SparkSQL statement?

For example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data   = array_of_table_and_time_tuples
                         , schema = StructType([StructField('table_name', StringType(), True),
                                                StructField('update_time', TimestampType(), True)]))
# something needs to be added here to make the dataframe reference-able by the SQL below

spark.sql(f"""merge {load_tracking_table} t
              using update_datetimes s
                on t.table_name = s.table_name
              when matched UPDATE SET t.valid_as_of_date = s.update_time""")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buried in the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically):

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("the_name_of_the_view")
```

so for the example above:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data   = array_of_table_and_time_tuples
                         , schema = StructType([StructField('table_name', StringType(), True),
                                                StructField('update_time', TimestampType(), True)]))

df.createOrReplaceTempView("update_datetimes")

spark.sql(f"""merge {load_tracking_table} t
              using update_datetimes s
                on t.table_name = s.table_name
              when matched UPDATE SET t.valid_as_of_date = s.update_time""")
```